# Перпендикуляр к осям

Tags: геометрия

Совершенно забыл геометрию с математикой.

У меня есть вектор с координатами, скажем, {1024, 768}, {600, 600}, где 1024, 768 - это правый нижний угол осей (точка 0,0 - слева вверху)

Скажите, как мне провести отрезок, проходящий через точку 600, 600 и края системы координат (размеры 1024x768), и перпендикулярный вектору?

**Добавлено.**

Тут всё ок
[image]

Смещаю и не ок, перпендикуляр строится к синей линии, а должен к красной.
[image]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где косяк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так. у Вас немножко сумбурно написано, поэтому перефразирую:

Есть точка А(1024, 768) и точка В(600, 500) (500 взято чтобы не путать размер по осям).
Тогда вектор АВ{600-1024,600-768} = {-424, -268} (числа меньше нуля - всё верно, вектор направлен к началу координат). Перпендикулярно ему будет вектор N{424, -268} или M{-424, 268} (они всего лишь направлены противоположно. для рассчетов брать любой). Проще говоря - по Х или У меняем знак - получаем перпендикулярный вектор (но это ТОЛЬКО для двумерного случая).

Дальше: уравнение прямой (возьмем вектор N{424, -268}):

- `x = 424*t + 600`;
- `y = -268*t + 500`;

Находим точки пересечения с осями:

- для `Х: У=0 => -268*t+500 = 0 => t = 500/268;` координата по `Х=424*(500/268)+600`;
- для `Y: x=0 => 424*t+600 = 0 => t = -600/424;` координата по `Y=-268*(-600/424)+500`;

Вот=)

**Если лень** разбираться, в общем виде:

- scr.x = 1024+1;
- scr.y = 768+1;// возьмите +1 чтобы не получилось деления на ноль;)
- p.x = 600;
- p.y = 500;

Ещё переменная `k = (scr.x-p.x)/(scr.y-p.y);` // вот тут чтобы не получилось деления на ноль

Тогда точки:

- с осью X: `[p.y*k+p.x, 0]`
- с осью Y: `[0, p.x/k+p.y]`

Comment: Спасибо!
http://gyazo.com/a88e645f035e8dab0f1b577608a712a2 - тут всё ок
http://gyazo.com/15da1486c569d257697cbab9835c6920 - смещаю и не ок, перпендикуляр строится к синей линии, а должен к красной

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где косяк?